# Deleting objects from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In SQL Server Database Engine I have a table named `Table A`.

I deleted the table using graphical interface, but when I wanted to create a table with same name, the error shows

> The object already exists

What is the remedy of this situation?

Comment: check it whether your sql management tool needs to commit your change.

Comment: You may refresh the SQL database and verify the existence of the table through the GUI.
In all likelihood, the table may have not been deleted. Hence, you are getting this error.

Comment: Did you "delete" it from a *database diagram*? Then you **only** removed it from that diagram - you **did not** actually delete the table itself from the database .....

Comment: Perhaps you deleted `Table B` instead of `A` :)

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should help you track down what is going on and help you create your table:

1. Right-click on your database and select refresh
2. Verify that your table does not exist under this database.
3. If you table is
   not shown here, then very likely your table is displayed under the
   master database.
4. To create a table in your selected database,
   first select the database and then run your query.
5. A better
   option for number 4, just to be sure you are specifying the correct
   database is to run the command `use dbname;` (where *dbname* is
   the name of your database). Do this on the line above your `create table` code.